# PostgreSQL, assign multiple records from one table to a single record from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in PostgreSQL. A table with donations and a table with features. I want to assign a donation_id to each feature, however some donation_id's should be assigned to multiple records in the table with features based on the ammount in the donation table.

For example: someone donated 10, then for every 2 a feature should be assigned to that specific donation_id = 5 records in the feature table with the same donation_id.

I'm looking for an update statement, since the features already exist and they all have unique values. It doesn't matter which feature gets assigned to which donation, only the quantity matters.

Donations:

```
donation_id | ammount
=====================
001         | 10
002         | 4
```

Features:

```
feature_id  | donation_id | owned
=================================
001         | 000         | false
002         | 000         | false
003         | 000         | false
004         | 000         | false
005         | 000         | false
006         | 000         | false
007         | 000         | false
008         | 000         | false
```

Output:

```
feature_id  | donation_id | owned
=================================
001         | 001         | true
002         | 001         | true
003         | 001         | true
004         | 001         | true
005         | 001         | true
006         | 002         | true
007         | 002         | true
008         | 000         | false
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What if the donation is not multiple of 2? What if there are not enough features to receive the donation?

Comment: If the donation is not a multiple of 2 it should be rounded. There will be enough features.

Comment: Did any answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Common Table Expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) (or two temporary tables, or some subqueries and redundancy), playing with a couple of tricks:

1. You can use a [`CROSS JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) (that is a Cartesian Product) with a [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) to get repeated rows. [We add a row_number() column to be able to distinguish them.]
2. You can choose a certain number of features by taking the `feature_id`s, and [`LIMIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html) the number of rows by using an expression. Again, we add a row_number() column to be able to distinguish them.

So, the following code does the trick:

```
-- Get a (virtual) table with "donation_id" repeated as many times 
-- as (amount/2). Trick: use a CROSS JOIN with generate_series
WITH new_features AS
(
    SELECT
         donation_id, row_number()  over () AS rn
    FROM
        donations 
        CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, amount/2) AS g(i)
),
-- Right now we know how many rows we want to UPDATE. 
-- The next SELECT chooses them. Trick: computed LIMIT
to_update AS
(
    SELECT
        feature_id, row_number() over () AS rn
    FROM
        features
    WHERE
        NOT owned
    ORDER BY
        feature_id  -- This is arbitrary, it could even not be sorted.
    LIMIT
        (SELECT count(*) FROM new_features)
)
-- ... and finally
UPDATE
    features
SET
    donation_id = new_features.donation_id, owned = true
FROM
    to_update
    JOIN new_features USING(rn)
WHERE
    features.feature_id = to_update.feature_id 
RETURNING
    features.feature_id, features.donation_id, features.owned ;
```

You can check it at [RexTester](http://rextester.com/LQG81274)

---

NOTES:

- I've assumed that `feature_id` is a primary key (or an alternate key: unique and not null). If this were not true, the appropriate PK is needed.
- Instead of using an `owned` column, it could be possible to just have a `donation_id` that when `NULL` means `not owned`. That would save a column, which would not have to be updated.